# Case-sensitive SQL differentiate between upper and lower case

Tags: sql, collation

I'm trying to have a request with a case sensitive result.

For example in my database I have

```
ABCdef
abcDEF
abcdef
```

The request is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 'abcdef'
```

but I have my 3 rows as result and I just want abcdef

I try to find a solution with

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'abcdef' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

but I have this error:

> Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS'{"success":false,"error":"#1273 - Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS'"}

Thanks

Comment: Well, first you should ask a question. Second, you should examine, why the collation is unknown.

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? SQL is just the query language - not a concrete database product....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your help I find the solution it was not latin1 ut utf8

```
COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Answer (score 1):

`Latin1_General_CS_AS` is a SQL Server collation.

For MySQL, try `latin1_general_cs`:

```
WHERE col = 'abcdef' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
```

Answer (score 0):

Case-sensitive string SQL differentiate between upper and lower SQL server 2008 R2
or after version you can be convert binary:

1. first step convert binary
2. last step compare two strings binary

exp:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM dbo.staffl WHERE CAST(unitcode AS BINARY(50)) = CAST ('pcs' AS BINARY(50))
```