# COLLATE case sensitive giving error (Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS')

Tags: mysql, sql, collation

As the title says, I'm getting the following error when I run this sql:

```
SELECT PASS FROM STAFF WHERE PASS COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'lucasL90';
```

Error:

```
Static analysis:
4 errors were found during analysis.
Unrecognized keyword. (near "COLLATE" at position 34)
Unexpected token. (near "Latin1_General_CS_AS" at position 42)
Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 63)
Unexpected token. (near "'lucasL90'" at position 65)
SQL query: Documentation
SELECT PASS FROM STAFF WHERE PASS COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'lucasL90'
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1273 - Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS'
```

Comment: what database engine and version are you using?

Comment: @Lamak MYSQLprovided by phpMyAdmin not sure what version but I supposed is the latest

Comment: Just check 4.7.3

Comment: `COLLATE latin1_general_cs` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262963/case-sensitive-sql-differentiate-between-upper-and-lower-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check collations available using

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET;
```

and then update your statement:

```
SELECT PASS FROM STAFF WHERE PASS COLLATE <one of the above collations here>  = 'lucasL90';
```

Comment: It's MySQL, btw.

Comment: Just seen that.

Comment: Thanks but I still got the following error. 

Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "COLLATE" at position 47)
Unexpected token. (near "Latin1_General_CS_AS" at position 55)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT PASS FROM STAFF WHERE PASS = 'lucasL90' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

MySQL said: Documentation

#1273 - Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS'

Comment: It shows the available collations. but still doesnt work i tried this version **SELECT PASS FROM STAFF WHERE PASS COLLATE latin1_general_ci = 'lucasL90';**.

But still got the errors:  4 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "COLLATE" at position 34)
Unexpected token. (near "latin1_general_ci" at position 42)
Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 60)
Unexpected token. (near "'lucasL90'" at position 62)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT PASS FROM STAFF WHERE PASS COLLATE latin1_general_ci = 'lucasL90'

MySQL said: Documentation

Comment: was the collation latin1_general_ci in the list returned by SHOW CHARCATER SET?

Comment: yes it did. but I found out in another post. this one utf8_bin and it did work :)

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent Sql Server `Latin1_General_CS_AS` for MySql is `latin1_general_cs`

So you can change your query as follow:

```
SELECT PASS
FROM STAFF WHERE PASS COLLATE latin1_general_cs = 'lucasL90'
```

Comment: i got the following error: Static analysis:

4 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "COLLATE" at position 34)
Unexpected token. (near "latin1_general_ci" at position 42)
Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 60)
Unexpected token. (near "'lucasL90'" at position 62)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT PASS FROM STAFF WHERE PASS COLLATE latin1_general_ci = 'lucasL90'

MySQL said: Documentation

#1253 - COLLATION 'latin1_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'